# How to obtain previous page's URL in php

Tags: php

I want to redirect to login page to previous page.I've tried many ways to make it work but I didn't. When I echo I can see on browser and it works properly. However, when I try to redirecting but I can't.

```
**login.page**


<?php



 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
 $url2 =parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
 header("Location: $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]");



}

?>
```

```
**main.php**

<?php  
 
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
<a id='' href=' https://www.example.com/login.php>
<input type='submit'  name='send' i class='btn-basic  value='write'></a>
                          
}

?>
```

Comment: your question is misising so much details, try updating it!

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. What do you want to get?

Comment: You have a bad syntax error.  Try: header("Location: $url");

Comment: I've answered, but I don't know if it's specifically what you want since your question is quite broad and unspecific. Try adding some more details like what *exactly* you want the program to do.

Comment: now I will try I will let u know if it works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should try to find a solution yourself and if you get stuck post your attempt (relevant code) so the people here can recreate your problem and give you advice on how to fix it. Here is a link with some information on how to improve your Question: [stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of login pages I have seen use a query parameter to refer to what site/page redirected them to the login web page.

From the previous page you can go to the login page with a query url like `"https://example.com/login.php?from=https://example.com/myhomepage"` (obviously change the data to the referrer you are redirecting from). Then when you login you redirect back to that web page by accessing the GET parameter `from` like so:

```
header("Location:" . $_GET['from']);
```

(I'm a little rusty with my PHP so just let me know if the syntax is wrong).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I came across"? Did you copy and paste the code? You have to tweak it to redirect back to the actual website. If it's the same site you might also want to leave out the "https://example.com" (or whatever the name of your website is). @dave

Comment: So it's redirecting to "example.com/login.php?%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20from=https://example.com/myHomepage" instead. You have to change "example.com" and "/myHomepage" to the URL you want it to redirect to.

Comment: LOL I told you I was rusty (had a syntax error). I edited my answer, check it again. It worked for me.

Comment: appreciated but I got it I used urldecode into href thanks to you     thank you reality u saved me